# How to add progress bar in forest tree node?

Tags: forest

I'd like to add below some nodes in my tree a progress bar.

Something like this:

[image]

My tree code is the following:

```
\package{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
[Asp \textsubscript{Habitual} [solere\\]
[Asp \textsubscript{Predispositional}
[tendere]
[Asp \textsubscript{Repetetive \textsubscript{i}} [tornare]
[Mod \textsubscript{Volition}
[volere][,phantom]
]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Whereas my progress bar code is the following:

```
\package{progressbar}
\begin{document}
\progressbar[linecolor=black, filledcolor=green]{0.6}\llap{\raisebox{1.5pt
{\tiny$60\%$}\hspace{0.8cm}} 
\end{document}
```

How can I combine these two together? I tried adding the progress bar code after each node, but it's as if the code doesn't work within the forest environment.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Since `progressbar` uses TikZ itself, there might be conflicts when using a progressbar inside a forest, i.e. nesting tikzpictures. How are you trying to use `\progressbar` as part of the node? You will have to wrap the whole thing in `{}` since `,`, `[` and `]` should not be interpreted by forest.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, using the following code and wrapping `\progressbar` in `{}`:

`\begin{forest}
 for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
 [Asp \textsubscript{Habitual} [solere
 {\progressbar[linecolor=black, filledcolor=green]{0.6}\llap{\raisebox{1.5pt}{\tiny$60\%$}\hspace{0.8cm}} }]
 [Asp \textsubscript{Predispositional}
 [tendere]
 [Asp \textsubscript{Repetetive \textsubscript{i}} [tornare]
 [Mod \textsubscript{Volition}
 [volere][,phantom]
 ]]]]
\end{forest}`

But it outputs the node **solere** with an overlapping **60%**, without the bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `\progressbar` uses TikZ internally and nesting TikZ pictures is at least annoying, we can make `\progressbar` forget to create its own `tikzpicture`.

Since the bar is created asymetric (the left-most point is at *x* = 0) we'll put it inside a matrix which in turn can be placed like a node which allow us to use a `label`.

I've added a `progressbar` key to forest that accepts four arguments:

1. options to `\progressbar`,
2. progress value and
3. options to the text node with
4. its content.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest, progressbar}
\forestset{
  progressbar/.style n args={4}{
    label={[matrix, inner sep=+0pt]below:%
      \let\tikzpicture\scope
      \let\endtikzpicture\endscope
      \progressbar[{#1}]{#2}
      \path (Begin) -- node[{midway,anchor=center,node font=\tiny,#3}] {#4\,\%} (End);
      \expandafter\pgfmatrixendrow}}}
\progressbarchange{linecolor=black, filledcolor=green}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} for tree={calign=fixed edge angles}
[Asp \textsubscript{Habitual}
  [solere, progressbar={}{.6}{}{60}]
  [Asp \textsubscript{Predispositional}
    [tendere, progressbar={filledcolor=yellow}{.3}{}{30}]
    [Asp \textsubscript{Repetetive \textsubscript{i}}
      [tornare]
      [Mod \textsubscript{Volition}
        [volere, progressbar={filledcolor=blue, width=1cm}{.85}{white}{85}]
        [,phantom]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by specifying this code after the terminal node I want the bar to be:

```
[volere, tikz={\node[below=-2.5pt of .south]  
{\progressbar[linecolor=black, filledcolor=green]{0.6}\llap{\raisebox{1.5pt
{\tiny$60\%$}\hspace{0.8cm}}};}]
```

The full code is the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
 for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
 [Asp \textsubscript{Habitual} [solere]
 [Asp \textsubscript{Predispositional}
 [tendere]
 [Asp \textsubscript{Repetetive \textsubscript{i}} [tornare]
 [Mod \textsubscript{Volition}
 [volere, tikz={\node[below=-2.5pt of .south]  { \progressbar[linecolor=black, filledcolor=green]{0.6}\llap{\raisebox{1.5pt}{\tiny$60\%$}\hspace{0.8cm}}};}][,phantom]
 ]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```